# ocaml graph traversal: how can I keep the visited node?

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to traverse a graph with DFS.

But when I tried to pass visited node list as a function's parameter, I found there is a problem.

When I reached at the node which has no connected node except its previous node, the recursive call ends and the information about visited nodes disappears so fall into infinite loop...

Is there an any way to keep an information about visited nodes except using imperative way?

Comment: I don't know OCAML, but can you pass a set around that contains visited nodes?

Comment: I'm a novice of ocaml, but ocaml is value-oriented language so once the value of a variable is set, there is no way to change the value except using imperative way which is not preferred way in functional programming....

Comment: In Clojure (functional), when you add to a set, you get a new set. There are constructs in the language that support this notion.

Comment: I appreciate your comment. I'll keep finding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Elaborating on Jeffrey's answer, you have several different styles available. I give here only snippets that I haven't tested, so there may be small or large mistakes.

1. You can use side-effects everywhere:

   ```
   module NodeSet = Set.Make(...)

   let traverse action graph_root =
     let visited = ref NodeSet.empty in
     let rec loop node =
       action node;
       visited := NodeSet.add node !visited;
       let handle child =
         if not (NodeSet.mem child !visited)
         then loop acc child in
       List.iter handle (children node)
     in loop graph_root
   ```

   The "visit" applies the imperative function `action` to all nodes in
   the graph.
2. You can store the visited node in a mutable reference, but thread
   the state of the traversal as an accumulator `acc` instead of
   sequencing side-effects directly. This would correspond to a use of
   the State monad.

   ```
   let traverse action init_state graph_root =
     let visited = ref NodeSet.empty in
     let rec loop acc node =
       let acc = action acc node in
       visited := NodeSet.add node !visited;
       let handle acc child =
         if NodeSet.mem child !visited
         then acc
         else loop acc child in
       List.fold_left handle acc (children node)
     in loop init_state graph_root
   ```
3. You can reuse this state-passing logic to also pass the visited
   node information.

   ```
   let traverse action init_state graph_root =
     let rec loop acc visited node =
       let acc = action acc node in
       let visited = NodeSet.add node visited in
       let handle (acc, visited) child =
         if NodeSet.mem child !visited
         then (acc, visited)
         else loop acc visited child in
       List.fold_left handle (acc, visited) (children node)
     in loop init_state NodeSet.empty graph_root
   ```
4. Finally, you can move to a tail-recursive traversal by passing
   information about which nodes should be computed next in the first
   recursive call. This corresponds to a general transformation into
   Continuation Passing Style, but with a domain-specific representation
   of continuations (simply nodes to visit).

   ```
   let traverse action init_state graph_root =
     let rec loop acc visited = function
       | [] -> acc
       | node::to_visit ->
          if NodeSet.mem node visited then loop acc visited to_visit
          else begin
            let acc = action acc node in
            let visited = NodeSet.add node visited in
            let to_visit = children node @ to_visit in
            loop acc visited to_visit
          end
     in loop NodeSet.empty init_state [graph_root]
   ```

   Jeffrey remarks that with this presentation, you can change the
   traversal order from DFS to BFS by simply changing the way `to_visit`
   is updated, adding children nodes to the end of the sequence rather
   than at the beginning (which requires a queue structure to be
   algorithmically efficient).

Comment: in 4., shouldn't you filter out already visited nodes? Like `let to_visit = children node @ to_visit |> List.remove_if (flip NodeSet.mem visited) in …`

Comment: well spotted @unhammer, thanks. I have changed the code to check for already-visited just before visiting, rather than filter out at children gathering time. If I remember correctly, it is not correct to only filter at children-listing time (because the node may already be in the to_visit list). Checking only at visting-time is rather inefficient because there may be many duplicates put in `to_visit`, but the code shape scales better to weighted-edge applications such as Dijkstra where not all ways to come to an edge are equal.

Comment: "it is not correct to only filter at children-listing time (because the node may already be in the to_visit list)" – I'm not sure I understand; the snippet in my comment filters the *concatenation* of children and to_visit. I can't get it to fail when I test it, but I don't know if I can prove it to be correct either :-) Do you have a counter-example?

Comment: Ah, found one counter-example at least: in a labelled graph, there may be two edges to the same node with different labels, so to_visit might end up getting the same child twice in one go

Answer (score 2):

One way to look at this is that you want to go *forward* to try other possible nodes in the graph, rather than returning (as you would do, say, to traverse a tree). You can have parameters that describe not only the nodes you've visited but the ones you are planning to visit. The to-visit parameter is initially just the first node. Every time you get to a new node you add any unvisited adjacent nodes (which you can tell by looking at the visited node set) to the *unvisited* node set, and continue in this fashion recursively. The difference between DFS and BFS, then, would be in the way you order the list of nodes to be visited.

In functional programming, there are many times when instead of returning from a function, you instead *call* a function to do the next thing. (That's why tail recursion is sometimes important.)